# Testing 3D touch with iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, ios9, 3dtouch

**Questions:**

I was wondering if anyone has tried **3D touch feature** on a simulator or rather anyone know whether it actually works there or not.

I know it's a **hardware based feature** and support is there only for latest iPhone 6S & iPhone 6S Plus models.

On an iPhone 6S simulator, I have tried with `Hardware --> Force Touch Pressure --> Deep Press` but no gain.

Comment: your question is good one'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must develop on a device that supports 3D Touch. Simulator does not support 3D Touch,the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/) from apple, if you need the   more information related to this topic, visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491188/simulate-force-touch-3d-touch-on-iphone-6s-or-iphone-6s-plus-simulators).

**Update**

> The iOS simulator with **Xcode 7.3** beta has an option to **Use Trackpad Force for 3D Touch**

Comment: No thats not true. As I mentioned in my post, I see this option enabled on my iPhone 6 S simulator! You want to double check and edit your reply.

Comment: Look at @simon answer, Xcode 7.3 simulators support 3D touch

Comment: @DashAndRest -- the answer is I submitted as couple of month back , now xcode has added this function

Comment: Yes, that's great thing Apple, as usual, did!

Comment: @DashAndRest -- tanx buddy

Comment: @DashAndRest -- I am not seen the apple document for this any way I updated the answer

Answer (score 7):

Yes, we can not on Xcode 7.0

BUt there is a way to simulate this by using https://github.com/DeskConnect/SBShortcutMenuSimulator

This saved me once. Hope could save you.
Notice that this is using for **Quick Actions** of 3D force touch features.

Comment: this is just of the menu !

Comment: Current status: does not work on 9.2 simulator and newer.
9.1 works well.

Comment: Can confirm with @OndrejHanak, works fine on 9.1 but not newer simulators

Comment: It works fine on 9.1, iphone 6s plus simulator. and for other 3d touch capabilities, you need to use Flex on github.

Answer (score 6):

With Xcode 7.3 beta you can now use 3D touch using a Magic Trackpad 2 or the built-in in newer MacBooks.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you do not have Force Touch trackpad **AND** iOS device with 3D Touch. By using only the simulator, you can use [**FLEX**](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX).

It works on my Xcode 7.2.1 and iPhone 6S simulator.
But the tutorial to use in documentation is not quite right.

**For peeking,**
You need to move a bit of your mouse cursor to let it work while holding *Shift* + *Command*.

**For Popping,**
While holding *Shift* + *Command* during peeking, press *Control* 3 times to pop out. I think 3 times means the hardest force applied, as the document stated, each key contributes 1/3 of maximum possible force.

Comment: Hello there, I am trying without force touch trackpad. Cant simulate the 3D touch in 6S simulator from the github example of FLEX. Can you help me with that?

Comment: It works for me in my project with 3D touch feature implemented by myself. Perhaps you should try on the project your own instead of the github example.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of code here that allows you to test 3D Touch peek & pop in the simulator. Bear in mind this is code for iOS 9.0, and some of the internal/private methods have changed in 9.1 (Hint: the word 'Position' changed to 'Location' in one of the method names).

https://gist.github.com/nickfrey/07e2c6d8d2e5444fb91d

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode 7.3 we can use Macbook's force touch trackpad to deliver touch pressure events to iOS simulator.

Ensure iPhone 6s/ iPhone 6s plus simulator is selected or else "Use trackpad ..." option will appear disabled

Answer (score -7):

You can do with shortkeys present on the simulator, under Hardware > Force Touch Pressure

command + shift + 1 for shallow touch

command + shift + 2 for deep touch

Comment: No that does not work. In fact if you see Anbu answer below, per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/) : **Simulator in Xcode 7.0 does not support 3D Touch.**

Comment: yes right couldn't get it working, I hoped that the options are there, may be there is some ways, I tried with the forcetouch trackpad didn't work either :|

Comment: Those options are just for watch.