# Does Xcode 7.1 beta 3 support 3D Touch on Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, 3dtouch

According to Apple documentaion,"Xcode 7.0 you must develop on a device that supports 3D Touch. **Simulator in Xcode 7.0 does not support 3D Touch**".Now Xcode 7.1 beta 3 is available.I want to know Xcode 7.1 beta 3 supports 3D Touch on simuator.If it supports, how to check on simulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing 3D touch with iOS Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007637/testing-3d-touch-with-ios-simulator)

Comment: I ask about **Xcode 7.1 beta 3** ,not **Xcode 7.0**.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.Some one has asked about this but commented people do not mentioned the answer.They have said,add this question as new question.Anyway I used this controller (https://github.com/DeskConnect/SBShortcutMenuSimulator) to test 3D Touch on simulators.

Comment: Can we check peek and pop option on simulator (I use Xcode 7.1) ?

Comment: Just the 3rd party option like the one in your comment.

Answer (score -2):

The third party library that you provided has some users that complained that it's not working on Xcode 7.2.

However you can use [**FLEX**](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX).

It can support 7.1 and above by just importing the framework via Cocoapods.

But the tutorial to use in documentation is not correct.

For peeking,
You need to move a bit of your mouse cursor to let it work while holding Shift + Command, not Command + Control + Shift.

For Popping,
While holding Shift + Command during peeking, press Control 3 times to pop out. Because 3 times means the hardest force applied, as the document stated, each key contributes 1/3 of maximum possible force.

Comment: Imagine the link behind "this" breaks. Then this answer is just a complaint about another answer; a comment, instead of a self-contained answer.

Comment: Link has been changed.