# Touch ID and Forch Touch Pressure option is disabled on Simulators

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I've attached the image below which is a screenshot of `iPhone` `Simulator's` hardware options, I'm new to `Xcode7.3.1` and want to know

- When the disabled options like **Force Touch Pressure, Touch ID Enrolled, Show Apple TV Remote** will get displayed.
- I want to implement `Forch Touch`, `Touch ID` and `3D Touch` in my app, but these options are disbaled.
- I'm using `OSX 10.11.5`

Please guide me how to enable these features

[image]

Comment: Is this iPhone 6S or 6S Plus simulator?

Comment: Yeah its iPhone 6S

Comment: Touch ID gets enabled for iPhone 6S, previous screen shot was for iPhone 4S :)

Comment: Hope this link help you [how-to-enable-force-touch-pressure-on-ios-simulator-9-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318329/how-to-enable-force-touch-pressure-on-ios-simulator-9-1)

Comment: Use Trackpad Force for 3D touch is not enabled because may be your Macbook trackpad does not have Force touch feature ?

Comment: Oh now I got it, thanks Forch Touch Pressure is for Apple watch, Trackpad 3D Touch is to use on MacBook, Touch Id will get enable if you have iPhone 6 or later devices

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure to enable “Force Click and haptic feedback” in System Preferences → Trackpad
2. Be sure you are using iPhone 6s/6s plus simulator.
3. IOS 9.3 seems required.

Comment: If I do not have macbook, do I need to buy separate trackpad to test 3D touch?

Comment: Oh, i guess so. I guess if you are using iMac without magic pad you can't enable "Force Click ..." option. My suggestion is borrow one iPhone 6s/plus from your friend? just test it that's it.

Comment: Well, my friend and me do not have iPhone 6s/plus, its a huge investment though. Is there no other alternative ? :(

Comment: I see. If's so just be ENOUGH confident with your code may be the last/only option.