# How to enable 3D Touch on ios simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, 3dtouch

I am fully aware that 3D touch can only be tested on hardwares having the capability. But is there any tweak or something to enable 3D Touch in simulator as I cant just buy another iPhone solely for this purpose.

Comment: Try this for Context menus, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32724910/366346. But 3D touch in apps are not supported on iOS simulators. [Apple Says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543) `With Xcode 7.1 you must develop on a device that supports 3D Touch. Simulator in Xcode 7.1 does not support 3D Touch.`

Comment: @GoodSp33d Yes, didn't see that before 