# How can I test force touch peek and pop in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

When I search Google, I got SBShortcutMenuSimulator, it's can simulator Quick Action operate in iOS simulator. But, how test peek and pop operate?

Comment: As I know.you can't.

Comment: You can't for the moment. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491188/simulate-force-touch-3d-touch-on-iphone-6s-or-iphone-6s-plus-simulators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find way! If your have MacBook Pro with ForceTouch Trackpad, you can do it.

Follow:
Choose iOS 9.3 with iPhone 6S Simulator, Find Hardware option on menu bar, check "Use Trackpad force for 3D Touch", then use your force touch Trackpad simulate 3D Touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FLEX to check it on the simulator. Using a combination of the command, control, and shift keys, you can simulate different levels of 3D touch pressure in the simulator. Each key contributes 1/3 of maximum possible force. Note that you need to move the touch slightly to get pressure updates.

https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX

Just remember to **exclude FLEX from Release (App Store) Builds**

Comment: Hello there, I am trying without force touch trackpad. Cant simulate the 3D touch in 6S simulator from the github example of FLEX. Can you help me with that?