# Width of 3d touch QuickAction menu same on iPhone 6s and iPhone 6s plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch, quickaction

I integrated `3d touch QuickActions` for my iOS app made with Xcode and Swift. Since I only have an iPhone 6s **plus**, I'm not able to test it on an iPhone 6s. The title is long and fills the line without overflow. But how is it on iPhone 6s? Will the text cutted there? Or does the menu have the same size as on iPhone 6s **plus**?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, from the images I've seen, the 3D Touch menu is the same width (3 App Icons) between the 6s and the 6s plus, but it looks like they are scaled so it is likely that the text won't be truncated(cut).

If you have Xcode 7.3, you can also check for yourself in the iOS Simulator with a third party library (or maybe a force touch enabled trackpad?): [Simulate force touch / 3D touch on iPhone 6S or iPhone 6S Plus simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491188/simulate-force-touch-3d-touch-on-iphone-6s-or-iphone-6s-plus-simulators/37932698#37932698)