# 3D Touch on Xcode 8 & Simulator 10

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8

I've read a [ton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491188/simulate-force-touch-3d-touch-on-iphone-6s-or-iphone-6s-plus-simulators) of threads debating if 3D touch is available on the latest Xcode 7 versions. The consensus was that it's possible but only with a 3D phone or trackpad. My question is if with the new Xcode and Simulator, has that changed?

I'm on a 2012 MacBook running Sierra:

[image]

I can see some force touch options:

[image]

But can I somehow enable those options so I can starting testing my 3D Touch code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To test 3D touch in the simulator, you would need a force-touch trackpad (i.e. a MacBook with a force-touch trackpad built in, or a Magic Trackpad 2). If you have one, those menu items come to life. If you don't have one, you can only test on a device!

Comment: I can confirm that I did go buy a Magic Trackpad 2 and it does allow me to test 3D Touch

Comment: Thanks for reporting back on that!

Comment: yeah you cannot simulate 3d touch be selecting some option or longer time in settings you must buy something apple branded :)

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you also have a device that can support it lol. Had simulator set up to iPhone 5S/SE and didn't realize why it wasn't working (*head slap*)

Answer (score 3):

Only a MacBook Pro or MacBook 12' after 2015 is shipped with a force-touch trackpad which you can use to simulate 3D touch in Xcode's simulator. You can check that with your mac in System Preferences->Trackpad->Point&Click.

[image: screen shot of Trackpad here]