# Simulator 3d Touch not available option in xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3dtouch

I have added the following options in the app's plist

```
<code>
 <key>UIApplicationShortcutItems</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>DisplayFav</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
        <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeSearch</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>Search For</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
        <string>Search for an item</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>WorkMore</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
        <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeHome</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>Work More</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
        <string>Working More ?</string>
    </dict>
        <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>RateAction</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
        <string>rate</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>Rate</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
        <string>Rate this app</string>
    </dict>
    </array>
</code>
```

Yet, the option to test this in simulator IPhone Xr is not showing. When I try to test, the option is disabled. Xcode is 10.2

[image]

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670021/3d-touch-on-xcode-8-simulator-10/40315236

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D Touch on Xcode 8 & Simulator 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670021/3d-touch-on-xcode-8-simulator-10)